# Moving lines with bash when there's text above or below

Tags: bash, grep, sed

I have a `file.txt` that looks like so:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

I wanted it to look like:

```
foobar
foobar
```

`foo` is always the beginning of the "primary" line and `bar` of the "secondary" one.

The closes I've been is this:

```
sed -n '1{h;n;G};p' file.txt
```

But this command just changes order so instead of the desired output, I get:

```
bar
foo
foo
bar
```

Any idea?

Comment: The following works for your example: `sed -n '/foo/{N;s/\n//p}'` - this finds `foo`, reads the next line, then removes the new-line between them. Depending on your precise conditions you may want to anchor the match with: `sed -n '/^foo$/{N;s/\n//p}'`. [This](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html) is quite a good reference.

Comment: @AFH first example works as expected, please make it an answer so I can give you your points :3

Comment: I've submitted my answer: I've left in the comment about anchoring for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for your example:

```
sed -n '/foo/{N;s/\n//p}'
```

This finds `foo`, reads the next line, then removes the new-line between them.

Depending on your precise conditions you may want to anchor the match with:

```
sed -n '/^foo$/{N;s/\n//p}'.
```

Some of the advanced features of `sed` can be quite daunting, but [this](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html) is quite a good reference.